# Is there a single word for reasoned action?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word which means "a well thought out action".

In other words, if someone were to plan something carefully, and act on that plan.

For example, a general faces an intractable foe on the battlefield, but thinks carefully on the solution and then acts - defeating the opponent easily. What could we call the action?

N.B. While interesting, I'm not really looking for words which imply "underhanded" or "risky".

Comment: Could you provide more context around your intended use of the term you seek?

Comment: A strategy? Context, please. Context.

Comment: For example, a general faces an intractable foe on the battlefield, but thinks carefully on the solution and then acts - defeating the opponent easily. What could we call the action? Sorry if this is still vague.

Comment: I wonder whether the question is clear, because nearly all of the answers so far are not actions, but the first line clearly calls for a kind of action. The last line combined with the first, however, suggests that the action needs to be considered and either underhanded or risky.

Comment: I added the note later, but many of the answers are close to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Have a look at these links ([from tag info](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info), [from the meta site](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7699/what-is-wrong-with-my-question)) in relation to the comments about context and examples.

Answer (score 4):

**Stratagem**:

> an artifice or trick in war for deceiving and outwitting the enemy.

(Source: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stratagem))

Answer (score 2):

***Strategy***

A careful plan or method.

Another option:

***Gambit***

A planned series of moves at the open of a chess game

A calculated remark intended to start a conversation or make a point

A calculated move

(Definitions from Merriam Webster)

Edit: adding another

***Rout***

An overwhelming defeat - or to defeat overwhelmingly

Comment: Gambit implies an element of risk that is missing from the desired definition. Most gambits in chess are technically unsound or speculative.

Comment: None of those are actions.

Comment: Rout is a verb in the 'defeat overwhelmingly' definition. More clarification  might be needed to determine whether OP wants a word meaning ' action' or an actual verb.

Answer (score 1):

Consider **maneuver**:

> A planned and regulated action (often military);an adroit move,
>   skillful proceeding, etc., especially as characterized by craftiness;

Answer (score 1):

***tactic***

> An action calculated to achieve an end. [FOD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tactic)
>
> An action or strategy carefully planned to achieve a specific end. [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/tactic)
>
> An action or method that is planned and used to achieve a particular goal. [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tactic)

Answer (score 0):

*Methodical* might work:

> methodical
>
> adjective me·thod·i·cal \mə-ˈthä-di-kəl\
>
> : done by using a careful and organized procedure
>
> : working in a very careful and organized way

Comment: It's not an action.

Answer (score 0):

A single word which means: a well thought out action carefully planed and then acted upon, culminating in an outcome, would be a *resolution*.

**resolution**, noun

> the action of solving a problem, dispute, or contentious matter. –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=resolution%20definition&oq=resolution%20definition&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.835j1j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)
>
> the act of finding an answer or solution to a conflict, problem, etc. : the act of resolving something | the act or process of resolving –[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resolution)

Comment: None of those are actions.

Comment: @Drew - Okay, let's try this one then.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when referring to the carrying-out of a complex plan, or series of actions, we use the word: ***implementation***.

"The *implementation* of the final phase of 'Project Brainwash', must be seamless."